# Creating consistent percentage-based sizing between mobile and web in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web application that will be used both in the browser and on mobile devices. My input field is currently set to 80% of the screen to leave room for an icon that I want to insert next to it later on.

My problem is that while 80% looks great on mobile [1] and leaves just enough room for the icon, it looks terrible in the browser [2] with the excess space. Increasing the percentage fixes the browser, but conversely ruins the mobile, etc.

[1]

[1 http://f.cl.ly/items/460K2T0Z3u3s2G3g3c2h/Image%202014-02-17%20at%201.17.18%20PM.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/460K2T0Z3u3s2G3g3c2h/Image%202014-02-17%20at%201.17.18%20PM.png)

[2]

[2 http://f.cl.ly/items/3W1N3y1X3P0Q282L0U2D/Image%202014-02-17%20at%201.17.27%20PM.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/3W1N3y1X3P0Q282L0U2D/Image%202014-02-17%20at%201.17.27%20PM.png)

How can I specify that I want a certain amount of the screen left to insert the icon, but still want the input form to stretch/shrink based on the size of the screen it's on?

Comment: You can always set your `inputs` to 100% wide, along with `box-sizing: border-box;`, and control the length of them via wrapping containers.

Comment: There is any code we can look into?

Comment: I have used EM hacks for width on stuff like this between mobile/desktop.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a larger issue to address. If the only problem is this single element's use of space, then the solutions presented here may work out. However, you will most likely need more control over how the application looks on mobile vs. the desktop. To address that, you'll want to look into CSS3 media queries. http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy with `calc()`:

```
.box {
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

This is assuming that you want to leave 30px of room.

Comment: Will accept the answer when I can in a few minutes.

Comment: @echo_Me Oh, sorry.  I thought it was totally off.

Answer (score 1):

Use the max-width value to set a 'maximum width', like this:

```
`max-width: 300px`
```

The bar will be 80% but no larger than 300px.